# SQL LIKE from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

Table1 with the column customerName in string:

```
1,2,3,101,102,customerA,customerB.
```

Table 2 with the changeID in string:00001,00002,00101,customerA.

Now I want to join these two tables, because I know changeID 00001 is customer 1, changeID 00101 is customer 101 and changeID customerA is off course customerA, but due to the zeroes I tried to use LIKE but failed.

Do you guys have Idee how to join these two tables?

Comment: Can you cast the id's to an integer? That would strip the preceding zeroes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The problem I also have characters in ChangeID like customerA. I will lose these values If I convert the format into integer.

Comment: I am just lost on what the columns are and what the strings are.  Can you provide data *in a text table*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an old "where join":

```sql
Select Table1.*, Table2.*
From Table1, Table2
Where Table1.ID = Val(Table2.ChangeID)
```

or:

```sql
Select Table1.*, Table2.*
From Table1, Table2
Where Right("0000" & Table1.ID, 5) = Table2.ChangeID
```

If that is too slow, write either of the tables to temporary table where the final ID and ChangeID will have matching data types.